# how does has_many :through work with only two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Just trying to work out how `has_many :through` works when there are only two models. I know there are a whole bunch of answers, but none seem to give an example with only using two models, all other examples are using three+ example models.

The question I would like answered is why is it that whilst in the rails console I get two completely separate results with the commands `a.friendships` vs `a.friends`, e.g. why does `a.friends` know to return the users object back to me? but `a.friendships` does not.

```
#User.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord         
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships
end
```

```
#Friendship.rb
class Friendship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"

end
```

```
irb(main):020:0> a = User.first
irb(main):016:0> a.friendships
  Friendship Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Friendship id: 1, user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, created_at: "2019-06-10 20:27:16", updated_at: "2019-06-10 20:31:41">]>
```

```
irb(main):020:0> a = User.first
irb(main):019:0> a.friends
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 2, email: "myemail@gmail.com", created_at: "2019-06-10 20:28:25", updated_at: "2019-06-10 20:28:25">]>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Everything you've shown looks correct... When you say `user.friends`, you get a CollectionProxy of Users, because friends are users. When you say `user.friendships`, you get a CollectionProxy of friendships, which are _records of relationships between users, not users themselves_. A friend is a User, a friendship is not a User.

Comment: What Glyoko has said makes sense. also, please paste your `Friend.rb` model.

Comment: Hi Glyoko, that commend was super helpful! If you want to make it into an answer I can accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

In designing a data model, you will sometimes find a model that should have a relation to itself. For example, you may want to store all employees in a single database model, but be able to trace relationships such as between manager and subordinates. This situation can be modeled with self-joining associations:

```
 class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id"

  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

With this setup, you can retrieve @employee.subordinates and @employee.manager.

Source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Answer (score 1):

```
users table
-----------
-id
-...
```

```
friendships table
-----------------
- id
- user_id
- friend_id
```

When you call `@user.friendships`, the target is to find `friendships` of `@user`. it returns objects from `friendships` table, the middle table, which hold the `relationships` between `users` and `users' friends`

When you call `@user.friends`, the target is to find `friends` of the `@user`. It is to join `users` table and `friendships` table, where `friendships.user_id = @user.id`, then, it gets all `friend_id` of from those `friendships` records, and find `users` who has `id` included in that `friend_ids` array.